# boost::multi_index_container MRU

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

I have a bmi multi_index_container for MRU defined as following

```
bmi::multi_index_container<Item, bmi::indexed_by<bmi::sequenced<>, bmi::hashed_unique<bmi::tag<hashed>, KeyExtractor>>>
```

It is actually based on the bmi [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/multi_index/example/serialization.cpp). Once inserting and relocating the item to head everything is ok. The problem starts when I'm looking up by a key and retrieving it as following.

```
item_type & get(const key_type & key) const
{
    auto item = items.template get<hashed>().find(key);
    if (item == items.template get<hashed>().end())
        throw std::logic_error("Item not found");

    //relocate the item to the head
    return const_cast<item_type &>(*item);
}
```

Since I'm looking it by the key I use the hashed index. Then I have to call `relocate` on the `sequenced` but the iterator from another index and it of course will not work. Sure, iterating over `sequenced` and finding the same item is an option but quite ugly and inefficient one.
Is there some other way to do it?

Comment: Doesn't iterator projection work in your case? https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/multi_index_container.html#projection

Comment: whoa! wasnt aware of it. Will check right away

Comment: @IgorR. it worked as expected. Thanks! Please convert you comment to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert between different indices' iterators, use [projection](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/multi_index_container.html#projection).